# How to click an element using selenium web driver which doesn't have an unique identifier?

Tags: button, selenium, click

Some of the buttons in my web page has dynamic ids and identical class names. please help me to access elements of that kind.

Comment: use xpath then ... and no, I cannot give you better answer as long as you have such vague question

Comment: Well what is the HTML or do we have to guess?

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug in firefox, you can select your element, then when it's highlighted, right-click on the highlighted part in firebug to grab the xpath. To click it use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your/xpath/expression")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons have similar ids and/or classnames but do have different text labels, you can access the buttons using the text

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forward"))
```

However, if the buttons do not have unique text labels this wouldn't work either.